# Converting a vector to digital ink

Tags: vector-graphics, file-conversion

Is it possible to convert a vector image to a digital ink xml using any known methods?

Digital ink is an xml format that contains the co-ordinates of the points. However svg is significantly different. Therefore, can you go from an svg to digital ink?

Furthermore, is it possible to do raster to digital ink?